# How to press CTRL+J (and CTRL+W) keys with Nightwatch.JS

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I need to close Chrome download bar with Nightwatch.JS. In order to do so I want to press CONTROL+J and then CONTROL+W.

However, the following code doesn't work:

```
client.keys([client.Keys.CONTROL, "\Ue006A"]);
```

Neither works:

```
client.keys([client.Keys.CONTROL, "j"]);
```

The thing is pressing CTRL+A in the same manner selects everything on the page. The following code works just fine:

```
client.keys([client.Keys.CONTROL, "a"]);
```

But not the CTRL+J.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`
under the chrome options so you will be able to access chrome://downloads